# What is the difference between `ethers.getSigners()` and `provider.getSigners()`?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I recently encountered both of these and I'm not able to find the difference between them. Are these the same or do they have some differnces?

Answer (score 2):

Basic difference among these two is basically that `ethers.getSigners()` returns `Signer` objects for accounts managed by ethers, while `provider.getSigners()` returns `Signer` objects for all accounts available on the connected Ethereum node